# Using structures in WindowsBase Assembly in Metro Applications

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to use `WindowsBase.dll` structures and classes like `System.Windows.Vector` in a Windows Store (aka Metro) like applications?

If yes, how? Which Reference should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, can't use that assembly in "Metro" apps